# filter + if results in "can't convert Array into String" error

Tags: logstash

We have beaver shipping logs to logstash. Two log sources are nginx error logs and haproxy logs. beaver is adding a tag for the log type and we'd like to parse the log according to type. We wrote the following configuration file but when logstash parses it we get the error: `can't convert Array into String` (`logstash -t -f logstash.conf` says the configuration is OK).

Any ideas how to fix this?

Here's `logstash.conf`

```
input {
    udp {
        port => 25826
        buffer_size => 2048
        codec => json
    }
}

filter {
    if "nginx-error" in [tags] {
        grok {
            match => {
                # 2015/12/24 14:27:38 [error] 8#0: *43449 upstream timed ...
                "message" => "%{DATESTAMP:timestamp} \[%{DATA}\] %{GREEDYDATA:message}"
            }
            overwrite => [ "message" ]
            add_field => {
                "levelname" => "ERROR"
                "levelno" => 20
            }
        }
    }

  if "haproxy-log" in [tags] {
        grok {
            match => {
                # [WARNING] 005/130716 (9) : Server app/app1 is ...
                "message" => "\[%{DATA:levelname}\] %{GREEDYDATA:message}"
                overwrite => [ "message" ]
                add_field => {
                    "levelname" => "%{levelname}"
                    "orig_levelname" => "%{levelname}"
                }
            }
        }
        mutate {
            gsub => [
                # Change ALERT to ERROR for easy query
                "levelname", "ALERT", "ERROR"
            ]
        }   
     }
}

output {
    stdout {
        codec => rubydebug
    }
}
```

FWIW: I got an a[nswer in the logstash forums](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/filter-if-results-in-cant-convert-array-into-string-error/38805).

Comment: Perhaps something in your input is an array, rather than a string.  What does your stdout{} show for the events?

Comment: Thanks @AlainCollins, that's what I ended up doing.